# Function Pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a function pointer and I am getting this error:

cannot convert from `void (__thiscall MyClass::*)(void)` to `void (__cdecl *)(void)`

```
// Header file - MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    void funcTest();
protected:
    void (*x)();
};


// Source file 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    x = funcTest;
}

void MyClass::funcTest()
{

}
```

(Using: Visual Studio 6)

Can anyone notice anything that I've missed?

Comment: How you are using this... plz paste more code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because a member function is different from a normal function, and hence the function pointers are different. Hence you need to tell the compiler that you want a MyClass function pointer, not a normal function pointer.youneed to declare x as: `void (MyClass::*x)();`

Answer (score 5):

The type of *non-static* member-function is not `void (*)()`. It is `void (MyClass::*)()`, which means you need to declare `x` as:

```
void (MyClass::*x)();

x = &MyClass::funcTest; //use fully qualified name, must use & also
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to assign a member function pointer to a standalone function pointer. You can't use the two interchangeably, because member functions always implicitly have the `this` pointer as their first parameter.

```
void (*x)();
```

declares a pointer to a standalone function, while `funcTest()` is a member function of `MyClass`.

You need to declare a member function pointer like this:

```
void (MyClass::*x)();
```

For more details see [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1).

Answer (score 1):

You declare a pointer to a function not taking any arguments and returning void. But you try to assign a member function pointer to it. You will need to the declare a pointer to a member function pointer and take its address like this: `&MyClass::funcTest` The type of this pointer is `void (MyClass::*)()` Have a look at the [function pointer tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes your type definition for `x` is wrong. You need to defined it as a member function pointer as suggested by the compiler, i.e., `void(MyClass::*x)()`.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html